# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin and I have added a parameter in the constructor and it throws this error? how to figure out the problem I don't understand. Any help would be appreciatable

```
Error public constructor AppView(context: Context, _listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener, _position: Int)defined in com.views.home.AppView @JvmOverloads public constructor AppView(mlist: StoreViewMap, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = ..., defStyle: Int = ...) defined in com.views.home.AppView




class AppView @JvmOverloads constructor(mlist: StoreViewMap, context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0) :
LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {
private lateinit var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener
private var position = 0
private val mainView: View
var mlistener: StoreViewMap = mlist

constructor(context: Context, _listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener, _position: Int) : this(context) {
    listener = _listener
    position = _position

    initFeed()
}

init {
    val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    mainView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_home_feed, this)
}

private fun initFeed() {
    mainView.homeSwipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener { fetchSlots() }
    loadContentSlots(DataCaching(context).getContentSlots())
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a default value to `mList` in your first constructor or add a `StoreViewMap`parameter in your second constructor

Comment: Your first constructor has 4 parameters, 2 with a default value, and in your second constructor you are calling your first constructor ->this(context) so the parameter mList is not provided and this is causing the error, you should call your first constructor-> this(mList,context) or provide a default value in your first constructor, like you are doing with attrs and defStyle

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your own constructor by calling this(context), which mean that if you define your constructor parameters calling the constructor will ignore them.

```
constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs)
```

Here the first constructor is calling the second and the second is calling the third, but the third is calling the constructor of the inherited class `LinearLayout` in your class.

The solution is to create a forth constructor and adding to it the params you want ex:

```
constructor(context: Context, mlist: StoreViewMap, _listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener, _position: Int) : this(context){
    // your code
}
```

This constructor will call the first constructor